# PSQL Hibernate Native insert values from a list

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, psql, hibernate-native-query

I have a table user_services

```
    Column     |  Type   | 
---------------+---------+
 user_id       | integer | 
 subservice_id | integer |
```

I have a SortedSet of subservice_ids in Java that I want to insert into my table each with the same user_id. Can this be done in a single INSERT-statement using native Hibernate SQL?

What if I do something like:

```
String values = StringUtils.join(mySubServiceIds, ',');

Query query = createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO user_subservices " +
"(user_id, subservice_id) " +
"SELECT 1 id, x " +
"FROM unnest(ARRAY["+ values + "]) x");
```

Would that work and be good?

Comment: If the native query would work on Postgres then it should also work from Hibernate.  Watch out for SQL injection though.

Comment: Anything that works from the `psql` console should work with native queries. Be aware though, that arrays are still unsupported in Hibernate, so you will have to write the `ARRAY[val1,val2]` syntax manually with escaped values. From what I'm seeing those are only numeric, which should be easy to verify.